# Updating the Actionbar menu in Actionbarsherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, menuitem

It's been giving me grief for weeks now. I have been wasting my time 4-5 hours a day and finishing other works by leaving this in the remaining time. But now it's back to haunt my dreams. Because the only thing I must do now is this. Can some one please let me know how to update the actionbar menu items? As if we want to update the data in the adapter(in ListView or spinner), it can be done by `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

But what is the thing that needs to be done for the `actionbar`? My requirement is this...

I have my actionbar on all activities. Suppose if a user clicks on `login(action item on actionbar)` on `4th` activity, he would be redirected to `login from` the fourth activity. After submitting the details I am finishing the login activity and redirecting the user to `5th activity`. `In the 5th activity I am displaying username(as an action item) instead of login option` with some help of shared preferences and manipulations.

But the actual problem is here ---> When I go back to 4th activity, The `login`(action item) is shown instead of **username**. Because I ain't doing any refreshment to the actionbar to update changes in the previous activity. This holds true with all the activities that are there in backstack. The only thing seems to me is to do something in the `onResume()` method, because when the activity comes front from the background this call back method will be called. But what should be done in that method? Hope my question is understandable. If some one wants any other details, please let me know. I would be very very thankful if someone helps me solve this.

**Note:** I don't want to refresh my activities in the `onResume()` as it is a hack and more over causes the data loss in the activity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

In all the fragment Activity write this in onResume().

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    this.invalidateOptionsMenu();

}
```

and then in

```
onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
```

Check whether the user has logged in. if so display username using the same technique you have used else display login menuItem.

Hope this solves your big problem.

Comment: Sadly, no. Because the invalidate option requires minimum api level of 11. I am using actionbarsherlock.

Comment: instead of this.invalidateOptionMenu() in onResume() since you are using ABS can you use this.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();

Comment: also use the latest version of ABS.

Comment: A 100 times thanks. BTW where did you find this? I did search a lot with no luck. But at least now I am lucky to have your answer. Can you also please look at my [unanswered question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196324/changing-the-background-of-the-action-bar-item-in-actionbarsherlock)?

Comment: I had done something similar with one of my project. But i didn't use ABS. I used API 11 itself as it was targeted for tablets. And since using ABS, most calls just use "supportSomeMethod()" i thought it would work for you as well.

Comment: Yeah. Nice thought. Do you have any idea on my another question?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```